# Adaptive images for images hosted on another server

Tags: javascript, image, responsive-design, adaptive-design

I am using [adaptive-images](http://adaptive-images.com) to make images re-sizing on my website. I have a javascript array that reads image urls from another website. There's javascript code that loops through the array of images and inserts these images on html page. I read the instruction for using adaptive image. This line of instruction is used when I store my images in a folder called 'myImages' :

.htaccess file provided by adaptive-images.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Adaptive-Images --------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} myImages
...
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that I get images from another website. So how do I edit the .htaccess file so it accepts images from another wesbtie

Here is the javascript code: (images are generated from another website like dummyimages.com for example)

```
var images = [
  "xyz.com/dummyImages/1.jpg",
  "xyz.com/dummyImages/2.jpg",
  "xyz.com/dummyImages/3.jpg",
  "xyz.com/dummyImages/4.jpg",
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
        $("#container").append('<div class="main">'
        +'<img src="'+images[i]+'" alt="sample photo" width="100%" />'
            +'</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: What? I'm sorry... Whaaaat? Please add details. You're using two servers!? On which is the .htaccess hosted?

Comment: the .htaccess is provided by adaptive-images.com and is at the root of my folder. images are generated from other website like http://dummyimage.com/